# Trying to convert a LATERAL SQL query to SQLA ORM/Core API calls

Tags: python, postgresql, sqlalchemy, flask-sqlalchemy

I have name translations stored in JSONB fields with the format `{lang-code: translation}` (from sqlalchemy-utils). I'm using `jsonb_each_text()` for retrieving the names in a query. Below is my model class

```
import sqlalchemy as sa
from sqlalchemy.dialects.postgresql import JSONB

from base import BaseModel


class Person(BaseModel):
    __tablename__ = 'person'

    id = sa.Column(sa.Integer(), primary_key=True)
    first_name_translations = sa.Column(JSONB, nullable=True)
    last_name_translations = sa.Column(JSONB, nullable=True)
    other_name_translations = sa.Column(JSONB, nullable=True)
```

This is the SQL I'm trying to express with SQLA:

```
SELECT
id,
first_name.value,
last_name.value,
other_name.value
FROM person
LEFT JOIN LATERAL jsonb_each(first_name_translations) AS first_name ON TRUE
LEFT JOIN LATERAL jsonb_each(last_name_translations) AS last_name ON TRUE
LEFT JOIN LATERAL jsonb_each(other_name_translations) AS other_name ON TRUE;
```

After checking SO and other places, I got something similar to this:

```
subquery = Person.query.with_entities(
    func.jsonb_each_text(
        Person.first_name_translations
    ).alias('first_name')
).subquery().lateral()

# raises error about ambiguous FROM
Person.query.filter(
    # ...
).outerjoin(subquery, sa.true())
```

But the above fails with an "ambiguous FROM clause"-type message from SQLA.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I was able to solve the query issue this way:

```
subquery = func.jsonb_each_text(Person.first_name_translations).lateral('first_name')
Person.query.filter(
    # ...
).outerjoin(subquery, sa.true())
```